Importing Bootstrap 5 and ngx-bootstrap 11 SCSS in Angular 16
I'm working with Angular 16 and have been trying to import SCSS files for Bootstrap 5 and ngx-bootstrap 11. I resolved the issue by adding the following configuration to my angular.json:
"architect": {
  "build": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
    "options": {
      "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
        "includePaths": ["../node_modules"]
      }
    }
  }
}

With this configuration, I'm able to import SCSS files from ngx-bootstrap. However, I noticed that Bootstrap 5 SCSS could be imported without this configuration.
Can someone explain why Bootstrap 5 SCSS works without specifying stylePreprocessorOptions while ngx-bootstrap 11 requires it? Is there a difference in how these packages are set up or loaded in Angular 16?
I want to know difference
